# Identifying the best fitting distribution type to test

Tags: machine-learning, distribution-identification

Hi I tried to analyze a dataset, of USDT concurrency and following is the frequency distribution I received for log return

[image]

I need this dataset to fit for a particular distribution. Can we suggest this which analyzing it using the histogram?

Statistical Values  USDT

```
Count   3917
Mean    -0.000005
Standard Deviation  0.007162
Variance    0.00005129
Skewness    2.2677868
Kurtosis    3.1428571
Minimum -0.076961
Maximum 0.104360
Median  0.000000
```

following are the descriptive statistics I used.

I need to use either excel or python for this

Comment: That is one ugly distribution.

Comment: yes. The analysis has been done using closing price log returns. Not the price was used. I have no idea here.

Comment: Have you tried using a normal distribution with the given parameters? See how well it fits? Try decreasing the variance too.